# python-pandas: dealing with NaT type values in a date columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe with mixed datatype column, and I applied `pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],coerce=True)` and got the below dataframe

```
CUSTOMER_name     DATE
 abc                 NaT
 def                 NaT
 abc               2010-04-15 19:09:08
 def               2011-01-25 15:29:37
 abc               2010-04-10 12:29:02
```

Now I want to apply some agg function (here i want to groupby mailid and take min() of Date to find that mailid's date of first transaction).

```
df['DATE'] = [x.date() for x in df['DATE']]
#Here the value goes to 
 CUSTOMER_name     DATE
 abc               0001-255-255 ####how??
 def               0001-255-255  ###How??
 abc               2010-04-15
 def               2011-01-25
 abc               2010-04-10
#Then when i do a groupby and applying min on DATE
df.groupby('CUSTOMER_name')['DATE'].min()
#CUSTOMER_name     DATE
 abc               0001-255-255 ####i want 2010-04-10
 def               0001-255-255  ### i want 2011-01-25
```

SO can anyone please suggest , how to deal with this NaT while converting to date() and while doing groupby and min(), how to exclude NaT for calculation.

### if for any customer_name only NaT will be there in DATE field, then on groupby and min(), I am okay with nan or Null values.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the `0001-255-255`. I get the same column of `df['DATE']` when doing `df['DATE'] = [x.date() for x in df['DATE']]`. Like @AmiTavory said in the answer, your code is fine on my end. I get `NaT` values when only `NaT` is there in the DATE field with groupby->min and groupby -> min ignores NaT values if it finds non-NaT dates

Comment: can you post a desired / expected data set or accept @AmiTavory's answer - if it answers your question?

Comment: @M.Klugerford:as in Ami Tovery example ,he formed dataframe with 'NaT' as string. In my case first take any string('sd','we','df') inplace of 'NaT', then do df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],coerce=True) then df['DATE'] = [x.date() for x in df['DATE']]. I am sure you will get 0001-255-255.

Comment: Still unable to reproduce @Satya What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'CUSTOMER_name': ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'def', 'abc', 'fff'],
...     'DATE': ['T', 'N', '2010-04-15 19:09:08', '2011-01-25 15:29:37', '2010-04-10 12:29:02', 'sa']})          Step-2) df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],coerce=True).         Step-3)  df['DATE'] = [x.date() for x in df['DATE']]   After this 3) i am getting those 0001-255-255 values. I am on pandas 0.16.1 and python 3.4.1

Comment: wow! `pandas 0.16.1` - it's a pretty old version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you start with something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CUSTOMER_name': ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'def', 'abc', 'fff'], 
    'DATE': ['NaT', 'NaT', '2010-04-15 19:09:08', '2011-01-25 15:29:37', '2010-04-10 12:29:02', 'NaT']})
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
```

(note that the only difference is adding `fff` mapped to `NaT`).

Then the following does what you ask:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.groupby(df.CUSTOMER_name).min())
CUSTOMER_name
abc   2010-04-10 12:29:02
def   2011-01-25 15:29:37
fff                   NaT
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This is because `groupby`-`min` already excludes missing data where applicable (albeit changing the format of the results), and the final `pd.to_datetime` coerces the result again to a `datetime`.

---

To get the date part of the result (which I think is a separate question), use `.dt.date`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.groupby(df.CUSTOMER_name).min()).dt.date
Out[19]: 
CUSTOMER_name
abc    2010-04-10
def    2011-01-25
fff           NaN
Name: DATE, dtype: object
```

Comment: :Thanks. After following your suggestion i got the result in datetime, Now how to convert that into date.I am getting same 0001-255-255 value inplace of NaT.

Comment: @Satya Not sure what you mean - the `dtype` indicates it is a datetime. If you'd like to convert it to a different format, please ask a new question.

Comment: @Amy- after df_new= pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.groupby(df.CUSTOMER_name).min()).reset_index() ....... I am trying to convert the datetime values of DATE column to date type('2011-01-25').. so i am trying that with df_new['DATE'] = [x.date() for x in df_new['DATE']]... Now in the o/p i am geting 0001-255-255 inplace of NaT.

Comment: @satya I've updated the answer, but note that you really ought to ask a separate question.

Comment: @Ami-Sure, though i will take your suggestion,but i have already asked this part( how to deal with this NaT while converting to date() and while doing groupby and min(), how to exclude NaT for calculation) in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

**Data:**

```
In [96]: x
Out[96]:
  CUSTOMER_name                 DATE
0           abc                    T
1           def                    N
2           abc  2010-04-15 19:09:08
3           def  2011-01-25 15:29:37
4           abc  2010-04-10 12:29:02
5           fff                   sa
```

**Solution:**

```
In [100]: (x.assign(D=pd.to_datetime(x.DATE, errors='coerce').values.astype('<M8[D]'))
   .....:   .groupby('CUSTOMER_name')['D']
   .....:   .min()
   .....:   .astype('datetime64[ns]')
   .....: )
Out[100]:
CUSTOMER_name
abc   2010-04-10
def   2011-01-25
fff          NaT
Name: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Explanation:**

first, let's create a new virtual column `D` with truncated time part:

```
In [97]: x.assign(D=pd.to_datetime(x.DATE, errors='coerce').values.astype('<M8[D]'))
Out[97]:
  CUSTOMER_name                 DATE          D
0           abc                    T        NaT
1           def                    N        NaT
2           abc  2010-04-15 19:09:08 2010-04-15
3           def  2011-01-25 15:29:37 2011-01-25
4           abc  2010-04-10 12:29:02 2010-04-10
5           fff                   sa        NaT
```

now we can group by `CUSTOMER_name` and calclulate minimum `D` for each group:

```
In [101]: x.assign(D=pd.to_datetime(x.DATE, errors='coerce').values.astype('<M8[D]')).groupby('CUSTOMER_name')['D'].min()
Out[101]:
CUSTOMER_name
abc    1.270858e+18
def    1.295914e+18
fff             NaN
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

and finally convert resulting column to `datetime64[ns]` dtype:

```
In [102]: (x.assign(D=pd.to_datetime(x.DATE, errors='coerce').values.astype('<M8[D]'))
   .....:   .groupby('CUSTOMER_name')['D']
   .....:   .min()
   .....:   .astype('datetime64[ns]')
   .....: )
Out[102]:
CUSTOMER_name
abc   2010-04-10
def   2011-01-25
fff          NaT
Name: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```